# C# UPDATE directly after INSERT but getting EXTRA INSERT

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've got the following code:

```
private void btnAddMatter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MatterCode = "";
    EntityID = 0;
    FeeEarnerID = 0;
    OpenedByUserID = 0;
    CompanyContactDetailsID = 0;
    Description = "";
    OurReference = "";
    TheirReference = "";
    DateOpened = DateTime.Now;
    MatterTypeID = 0;
    DepartmentID = 0;
    ResponsibleUserID = 0;
    TrustBankAccountID = 0;
    BusinessBankAccountID = 0;

    string connectionString = "Data Source=***\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=STUPELG;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Password=***";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Matter ( MatterCode, EntityID, FeeEarnerID, OpenedByUserID, CompanyContactDetailsID, Description," +
                                        " OurReference, TheirReference, DateOpened, MatterTypeID, DepartmentID, ResponsibleUserID, TrustBankAccountID, BusinessBankAccountID)" +
                                        " VALUES ( @MatterCode, @EntityID, @FeeEarnerID, @OpenedByUserID, @CompanyContactDetailsID, @Description," +
                                        " @OurReference, @TheirReference, @DateOpened, @MatterTypeID, @DepartmentID, @ResponsibleUserID, @TrustBankAccountID, @BusinessBankAccountID);" +
                                        " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MatterID", MatterID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MatterCode", MatterCode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntityID", EntityID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FeeEarnerID", FeeEarnerID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OpenedByUserID", OpenedByUserID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyContactDetailsID", CompanyContactDetailsID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Description);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OurReference", OurReference);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TheirReference", TheirReference);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MatterTypeID", MatterTypeID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentID", DepartmentID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResponsibleUserID", ResponsibleUserID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrustBankAccountID", TrustBankAccountID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessBankAccountID", BusinessBankAccountID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOpened", DateOpened);
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet NewMatterID = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(NewMatterID);
        MatterCode = Convert.ToString(NewMatterID.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
    }
   
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Matter SET MatterCode = @MatterCode WHERE MatterID = " + MatterCode);


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
    
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MatterCode", MatterCode);
  
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Matter " + MatterCode + " successfully created");
}
```

After the row is inserted, the new MatterID (primary key that is generated automatically) should be copied to the MatterCode field. Currently it works EXCEPT that there is an extra row that is generated at when the button is clicked:

[image]

How do I fix this???

Comment: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() and adapter.Fill(NewMatterID) will execute insert query twice

Comment: Just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Further points: 1. There is no need for an adapter as you are only returning one value, use `(int) (decimal) cmd.ExecuteScalar()` instead. 2. You are concatenating the value in the second query, use a parameter instead 3. You don't need to run two queries anyway, you could do the whole thing in one batch `INSERT` followed by `UPDATE ... WHEREMatterIid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. Don't forget you can only call `SCOPE_IDENITTY` once, if you need to reuse then save in a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - this is because **your code** is executing the `INSERT` query twice......

```
connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // first execution

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet NewMatterID = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(NewMatterID);  // second execution
```

I'm not entirely sure what you wanted to do with that `SqlDataAdapter` - but it's using the same `SqlCommand` from before, with the `INSERT` statement, which gets executed a second time......

Answer (score 2):

You can replace this:

```
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet NewMatterID = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(NewMatterID);
    MatterCode = Convert.ToString(NewMatterID.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
```

with

```
    MatterCode = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

as `ExecuteScalar` runs the command and returns the value of the first column of the first row of the first resultset.